# how to rotate a camera look where I'm moving in unity?

Tags: unity-game-engine, game-development

I'm making a drifting game and I want to make a first person camera that follows the direction the car is moving, not the front of the car. In the picture I want the camera to look in the direction of the red vector(which is the direction I'm moving towards), not towards the blue one, which is the front of the car.

[image]

I already made the movement script and I searched many tutorials, but I still don't understand. If you have an idea on this subject, please leave it here, any suggestion is helpful.

Comment: Stackoverflow is not for asking for advice on how to do something, it is about solving problems. Requests for suggestions for resources are not allowed. You should read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask, and https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's to clear where the camera is in this scenario. I like my cameras behind the car.
Presumably, you have a value for the red vector. If this is the case you can add it to the position of the car to get a world position.

```
Vector3 worldPos = redvector + car.transform.position
```

You can then use

```
camera.transform.rotation = Quaternion.LookRotation(worldPos - camera.transform.position);
```

to point the camera.

If the camera is at the position of the car it's even easier.

```
camera.transform.rotation=Quaternion.LookRotation(redvector);
```